# How do I install pdftk on Openshift?

Tags: openshift

Is there a way to install pdftk on Openshift

It is available on Fedora and Centos - I tried yum and apt get but neither works

I need it for a Sinatra App I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to use yum on OpenShift Online, as you do not have root privileges. You can try downloading the source and compile/install it into your app-root/data directory, or enter your request to have it installed here: http://openshift.com/ideas

Comment: I was afraid of that  I hope they have the compilers installed

Comment: Yep, we have compilers installed, i have compiled and installed many things into my app-repo/data directory, including cmake :)

Comment: Did you ever manage to compile pdftk on openshift? I've been stuck trying to compile it under my node 0.10 gear (unable to solve /bin/sh: gcj: command not found).

Comment: If there is a linux command that is available on Red Hat Linux that you need installed, you can suggest it here (uservoice.openshift.com) and have users vote on it.